# Should debugging with VSCode + Local + Xdebug throw 14K+ Problems?

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

Disclaimer: I'm new to development, so it's possible this is normal.

I've written some code I'd like to debug. I've followed like five tutorials on integrating Xdebug, local, and VSCode to all play nice.

When I try to debug, it's debugging the entire site, not just the one file I want it to look at. Furthermore, I'm getting 14K+ errors in a single site installation, and they seem to be more because VSCode doesn't understand WordPress than actual problems?

[image: Screenshot of VSC's debug console showing 14k+ problems]

I've tried installing a couple of snippet extensions, and added WordPress to my stubs. Here is my `launch.json` file:

[image: Screenshot of the contents of the launch.json file]

**Two questions:**

1. How do I only debug what I'm interested in rather than the whole damn site, and
2. why the heck do I have 14K+ problems and how can I make them go away?

Comment: Will only comment on #2 a bit: 1) the issue in focus on your first screenshot is that `@return post meta` is basically written wrong/used in a wrong way. The correct syntax is `@return [Type] [optional description]` So the `post` here is **correctly** treated as a PHP class name (as it's not a built-in simple type like string/int or alike and there is no `post` class in your project. I do not know why `@return` is even used for that particular comment block -- it's useless at that place as it is used for functions and not `if` blocks. BTW, PhpStorm (the IDE I use) should show the same notice.

Comment: If you look a bit below, how it is used in a PHPDoc comment for the actual `astra_get_post_meta` function, it is used there correctly -- the return type is declared as `string` and `post meta markup` is a description. Sadly I do not use VSCode and cannot say how (and if at all) this [particular check can be ignored. At the end of the day PHPDoc have their reasons and if it's used in a wrong way .... that should be addressed by the plugin/theme devs.

Comment: As for the debugging -- it may depend on what exactly you are trying to debug (a URL or a particular script), how you are launching the debug, if it's all local/any symlinks etc (the path mappings). Since it's a WordPress site, you need to debug a URL. In most cases the request will be handled by the `index.php` (the entry point) and then go though all WP code until it gets into the desired file/class. And normally it will work like that (the debugger will stop only at the breakpoint, if all paths are correct etc).